# IronPython + Winforms in a non blocking manner

Tags: winforms, ironpython

I have been doing Michael Foord's [IronPython&Winforms tutorials](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/winforms/index.shtml) in the interactive console.

Is it possible to remain in the console after the issueing

```
Application.Run(form)
```

so, I can put controls on the form while it is running?

The goal is to dynamically modify the WinForms controls at runtime, adding event handlers, changing properties etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With my installation (think I used the MSI) there is a Tutorial folder directly under the main IronPython one.

Inside the folder there is a Tutorial.htm file that has an example of just what you want, in the **Tutorial 2 -> Exercise 2 : Windows Forms** section.

Essentially you have to make sure the IronPython knows about the **winforms.py** file provided in the Tutorial folder, by either having it on the path or launching IronPython from a folder containing a copy of the file.

Then you can do

```
 import winforms
 from System.Windows.Forms import *
 from System.Drawing import *
 f = Form()
 f.Show()
```

Which will bring up a form for you, but leave the console interactive so you can change the form as you want to while it is running.

Comment: Great tip.  I tried running this example from an IronPython console under eclipse with no success.  You need to launch ipy.exe from a plain old command prompt.

Comment: there's no tutorial folder in latest distribution of 2020. I've been looking for that tool everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the `Application.Run(form)` in different thread.
See [my blog post](http://gui-at.blogspot.com/2008/06/exploring-test-application-ironpython-2.html) or Michael's one: www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/testing/testing-multidoc.shtml